# Allow users to edit CSS

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I love the features of TinyMCE, it makes for a very powerfull text area editor. I really like the 'Edit CSS Style' (styleprops) plugin that lets you edit further CSS options.

Is it possible to directly access this popup box to use on other elements/DIVs etc. rather than only having it within TinyMCE for the current textarea.

So for example, I have a DIV, write a jquery click function which opens up the 'Edit CSS Style' popup, then when the user applies changes they get applied to the calling DIV?

Look forward to any help.

Comment: I would rename your question to something like "Allow users to edit CSS", this doesn't have much to do with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, i do not think this is possible. The only way would be to alter the already existent tinymce plugin to your needs or copy the plugin, rename it and change the functionality.

Comment: I think what I may have to do is load a TinyMCE instance against a temporary textarea with only the CSS option on the menu bar, then when the user clicks 'Update' and closes the dialog it takes the style attribute of the textarea and sets the calling DIVs' style attribute to be the same. ??

Comment: I sussed it! As long as you have an TinyMCE instance initialised you can call tinyMCE.execCommand('mceStyleProps'); to return the style dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) allows for this sort of function, but it won't be something built into your pages without downloading it and you won't be able to save the results.

Comment: Thanks.  I really needed something 'permanent' where by the style values can be read and stored in a database.  I'm working on a solution now so will post how I get on.